# Travelling in the Schengen Area with Spanish National Visa. Would there be stamps?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, customs-and-immigration

I'm an Erasmus exchange student currently located in Madrid. I'm from Turkey so, to come here, I got a 6-month Spanish National Visa. For some volunteer work, I will travel to Estonia (with stopover in Germany) and back.

My question is whether, at any point, will my passport be stamped? I currently have the entry stamp into Spain.

I'm asking because Erasmus officials back home don't like it when we travel and I don't want it to become an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen Area functions as a single country for border purposes, so there will be **no border control** flying Spain-Germany-Estonia. Yes, it's just like a domestic trip (say, Ankara-Istanbul).

Although irrelevant, a few Schengen countries, especially Switzerland, perform selective border checks on entry **by land**, but those are just internal checks to see if everyone's in Schengen legally, and stamps are **not** issued during these.

But by air, no, your passport **will not even be checked** (except by the check-in desk if you have to go there, and *maybe* at the gate. That isn't border control though)